# What is the proper way to sign in as a user in an rspec request spec, without devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails application which has some User authentication which is built without Devise (or any gem for that matter). It uses the typical `session[:user_id]` to track the current user.

My understanding of the current state of controller tests is that the Rspec team and Rails teams both recommend against using them. This is fine, but I'm not seeing how to actually sign in as a user from within a request spec. I've done it with Devise with no issue, but Devise uses Warden and such.

I've tried to access the `session` from within the test but the level of abstraction within request specs seems to prevent access to it.

How can I sign in a user from within a request spec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the session before the request:

`@request.session['user_id'] = '1'`

Or add anything else that you require on the session to validate your user.

Or you could create a helper method that actually performs the request needed to login, which is what [@dhh recommends](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23386#issuecomment-178013357).

Comment: The code examples in the linked Github issues page were helpful in understanding how to properly set up a helper module. I've done it that way, and actually post to the controller for the login. Thanks for your help.